# Magento 2 coupon code is not used but it is show used on admin

Tags: magento2, checkout, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, coupon-codes

Magento version 2.4.5-p1.
In the Magento cart price rule, the coupon code is shown as marked on admin but it is not used from the frontend, and also coupon code is not visible when we checked from admin coupon reports.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide us screen shots and steps to re-produce given issue. Have you checked in Fresh instance of Magento 2.4.5-p1?

Comment: @Kamlesh it is coming only randomly